# Can not clear contents of set /p variable in win 7 cmd prompt batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which needs to kill processes which conform to a keyword. Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
REM tkill.bat  
IF [%1] == [] GOTO Syntx

tasklist | find /i "%1%" > ttt.txt
set /p line=<ttt.txt
for /f %%G in ("%line%") do set "pp=%%G"

if [%pp] == [] GOTO endit
taskkill /f /im %pp%
del ttt.txt
goto endit

:syntx
echo Syntax:
echo   tkill partial_process_name
:endit
set line=
```

Lets say I want to kill all opera browser processes. So I run:

```
tkill opera
```

and I get this output

```
C:\Windows\system32>tkill opera
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 3572 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 9320 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 6628 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 2220 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 4184 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 5816 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 9816 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 7416 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 684 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "opera.exe" with PID 4688 has been terminated.
```

So I check if there are any straggler processes

```
C:\Windows\system32>tasklist | find /i "opera"

C:\Windows\system32>
```

There are none.
Then I run the same command again and see the out:

```
tkill opera
ERROR: The process "opera.exe" not found.
```

Here is my problem: There is no opera.exe named process in the memory. Hence my 
`tasklist | find /i "%1%" > ttt.txt` command should result in an empty file. Yet the opera.exe name is getting stuck somewhere, until, either I close the dos prompt and open a new one or run the same command with a different process name which was actually running and get killed. Then the new name gets stuck in memory, such as :

```
C:\Windows\system32>tkill notepad.exe
SUCCESS: The process "notepad.exe" with PID 5952 has been terminated.

C:\Windows\system32>tkill notepad.exe
ERROR: The process "notepad.exe" not found.

C:\Windows\system32>tkill neon
ERROR: The process "notepad.exe" not found.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

There is something missing in my understanding of how windows variables are assigned, but what is missing I can't figure out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a `%` in `if [%pp] == [] GOTO endit`

Comment: N. B.: use quotes instead of `[`/`]` in `if` conditions, like `if "%~1" == "" goto syntx`...

Comment: You can avoid it if running `set pp=`. But for some reason the script is creating `pp` as an environment variable. You can check that with `set pp` on a different command prompt.

Comment: Try using `setlocal` at the beginning and `endlocal` at the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested**

Try adding `setlocal` and `endlocal` to the script.

It would also work fine using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and using `!` when necessarily.

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM tkill.bat

IF [%1] == [] GOTO Syntx

tasklist | find /i "%1%" > ttt.txt
set /p line=<ttt.txt
for /f %%G in ("%line%") do set "pp=%%G"
if [%pp] == [] GOTO endit
taskkill /f /im %pp%
del ttt.txt
endlocal
goto endit

:syntx
echo Syntax:
echo   tkill partial_process_name

:endit
set line=
```

If not `pp` is created as an environment variable and probably would store the last process found.

**Extra not necessary verbose:**

In the original `batch`, `pp` always stored  the last process found. But notice that, if we make three identical and consecutive executions, just for the second time the script is executed. No delayed expansion is enabled, it would take the value of `pp` at parse time rather than at execution time. Since for the second time `set pp=` is executed because the no process was found. The third time the original script would run fine.

Answer (score 0):

As it would be too problematic to allow for this program to match the input string anywhere within any running process, I'd offer this much simpler syntax in your `tkill.bat` file:

```bat
@If "%~1"=="" (Echo Syntax:&Echo   tkill partial_process_name)Else TaskKill /Fi "ImageName Eq %~1*" /F /T
```

You can split the above over multiple lines for easier reading, should you wish:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" (
    Echo Syntax:
    Echo   tkill partial_process_name
) Else TaskKill /Fi "ImageName Eq %~1*" /F /T
```

This requires no files to be written, read and deleted and no variables to be defined or otherwise. There is also no reliance on `find.exe` *(especially as the `ImageName Eq` option is already case insensitive)*. You'll also note, that there's no need to check the output from `Tasklist` in order to use `TaskKill`, if a matching process is not found then it cannot 'kill' it and will provide an `INFO:` message to let you know, *(instead of the `ERROR:` message you're currently receiving.)*.